# Jquery image overlay

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dynamic image gallery, the image for which are pulled from a database. What I need to do is to overlay the image with a colour, then remove the colour on mouseover. 
The colour is an 80% tint of blue.

I've found something similar on this forum which does the reverse of what I want - it adds the colour on mouseover (using Jquery) rather than removing it. However I'm not a Jquery expert and can't figure out how to re-write the script to set the colour initially, the remove it on mouseover.

Here's the current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#project1 a').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).parent('div').css({position:'relative'});
    var img = $(this).children('img');
    $('<div />').text(' ').css({
        'height': img.height(),
        'width': img.width(),
        'background-color': '#4f99ff',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'opacity': 0.8
    }).bind('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    }).insertAfter(this);
});

});
</script>

<div id="project1"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="614" height="218" alt="" /></a></div>
```

Can anyone suggest how to reverse the above function to do what I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add the overlay div statically on the page, on each image, and then hide it on mouseover, and show it on mouseout, with a nice fading effect. That would be something like this, which is simpler from a JS point of view:

```
<style>
#project1 {
    position: relative;
}
.blueoverlay {
    background-color: #4f99ff; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 0.8;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#project1').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find('.blueoverlay').hide();
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.blueoverlay').show();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="project1">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="blueoverlay" style="width:300px;height:300px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's more elegant than my solution. There's no need for the href if you change the selector to $('#project1 img') though.

Comment: Yes, the anchor seems to be useless to me, but as I don't know what he wants to do with it, I left it. Thanks for noticing anyway.

Comment: The anchor is to link to another page. I just didn't want to clutter the code with my link.
And I am a 'she' not a 'he'.
Thanks anyway, I will try your solution now.

Comment: Oops... Really sorry Kelly... :$

Comment: No problem PJP ;-) I know my name can be male or female!!

Comment: I am still struggling with this though - I don't usually work with Jquery - PHP/MySQL are more my thing. I've done what you've said above, but it has has no effect. I'm not getting a rollover effect or anything :-(

Comment: Here's the CSS & Jquery:
<style type="text/css">
#project1 {
   position: relative;
}
.blueoverlay { 
 background-color: #4f99ff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//$("#project1_desc").hover(function(){$(this).toggleClass("hover");});
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#project1 a').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('.blueoverlay', this)
        .fadeOut()
        .bind('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
});

});
</script>

Comment: And the code:
<div id="project1"><a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" width="614" height="218" alt="<" /></a><div class="overlay" style="width:614px;height:218px;">&nbsp;</div></div>

Comment: Moreover, I'm french, so I'm not really used to this name!

Comment: Please PJP, if you've any more ideas on this it would really be appreciated! The overlay colour now shows on page load, but nothing happens when I mouseover or mouseout.

Comment: OK, so here is some working code: http://jsfiddle.net/KLbrh/3/
I did a few mistakes in my original attempt.
It supposes that your "project1" div is a container for one and only one image. If it is not, you'll have to add a similar container, wrapping the anchor and the overlay, and modify the JS accordingly.

Comment: You're very welcome :-). When you'll be more at ease with JS/jQuery, maybe you'll be able to enhance it a little bit with fading effects for instance. But that's another topic, and I also got some work to do on my side! 
Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

That seems overly-complicated.
My solution would be to display a div with the photo as a background-image, then, inside the div, put a semi-transparent .png of the colour you want.
Assuming the div has the class "photoholder" and the semi-transparent image has the class "overlay":

```
<div class="photoholder"><img src="mypng.png" class="overlay" /></div>
<script>
    $(".photoholder").mouseenter(function() {
        $(".overlay").hide();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(".overlay").show()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Grim, but I'm unable to make that suggestion work at all.

Comment: Oops - did you add the class to the overlay image? I forgot in my code above (now edited). I'd go with PJP's solution anyway.

Comment: Your solution is great too, but I think it lacks the original image, in addition to the overlay. Am I right?
If I am, our solutions are pretty similar.

Comment: The original image would be the CSS background-image of the div in my solution. The downside is that you'd have to calculate the size of the image to make the div (or, more likely, the image inside the div) the right size.

Answer (score 0):

See the `.bind` parts (`$('#project1 a').bind('mouseover', function(){`
 and `}).bind('mouseout', function(){`
)? Just reverse the `mouseover` and `mouseout` parts, and it should work.

Comment: Yes that's true, and it's the first thing I tried. But what I also need to do is to set the overlay colour when the page loads, not just when you roll into it and then back out again. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, it's OK I found how to do it. It was simpler than I thought: $("#project1").css("background-color", '#4f99ff');
I was looking for a more complex solution.
Thanks for your help Shauna!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Don't forget to mark your accepted answer as answered. That way, people will be more apt to answer your future questions, and others looking for help will know what worked for you.